# Reducing all JS Promises before resolving to next then

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I can't seem to find the right solution to this problem.  I have a promise with a bunch of thenables and in one of the resolvers, I want to pause and do a series of work on an array (using promises), and I don't want this to actually resolve until the series of promises have completed.  This example seems to get me pretty close, but I think I might have created an anti-pattern.

http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/

```
// async_series.js
// example of using reduce and promises and closure to create async results in series

var q = require('Q');
var results = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function workCollection(arr) {

    return arr.reduce(function(promise, item, index) {

        return promise.then(function(result) {

            return (function(i, r, idx){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    console.log('item', i, 'result', r, 'index', idx);
                }, 1000 * idx);
                return true
            })(item, result, index);

        });

    }, q().then(function(){return true}));

}

    q()
        .then(function(){
            console.log('start');
        })
        .then(function(){
            workCollection(results)
        })
        .then(function(){
            console.log('done');
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
```

Kind of works, but the output is:

```
start
done
item 1 result true index 0
item 2 result true index 1
item 3 result true index 2
item 4 result true index 3
item 5 result true index 4
```

as opposed to this (intended):

```
start
item 1 result true index 0
item 2 result true index 1
item 3 result true index 2
item 4 result true index 3
item 5 result true index 4
done
```

Suggestions greatly appreciated.  Plz comment before down voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's multiple things:

- as already mentioned, you need to `return` the (promise) result of `` from the `then` callback, otherwise the chain won't wait for it
- `q().then(function(){return true})` should simply be `q(true)`
- The IIFE is useless. If you need a closure scope for anything, the `reduce` callback already provides it.
- You can't `return true` and expect anything to wait for the `setTimeout`. You'll need to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) it (wrap it in a `new Q.Promise(…)`), or just use [`Q.delay`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qdelayms).

All in all, your code should look like this:

```
var q = require('Q');

function workCollection(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(promise, item, index) {
        return promise.then(function(result) {
            return Q.delay(result, 1000);
        }).then(function(result) {
            console.log('item', item, 'result', result, 'index', index);
            return true;
        });
    }, q(true));
}

q().then(function(){
   console.log('start');
   return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
}).then(workCollection).then(function(result) {
   console.log('done', result);
}, function(err){
   console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: I love this answer because its so simple and readable and it works perfectly via Q for Node.  However, there appears to be an issue with Q in Chrome or perhaps I'm not using the Q object the right way here? https://jsfiddle.net/dzzas97p/6/  The items log at the same time.  Just curious as to why?

Comment: @4m1r It seems I misunderstood the Q docs. `promise.delay(…)` starts the timeout immediately, instead of waiting for `promise` to fulfill, so you need to explicitly put it a `then`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `promise.all()`.  Just push each of your array promises into an array (often name `deferred`) and then return `promise.all(deferred)`

Documentation here: https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promise-for-array-methods

**Update**

Rather than edit your fiddle, I created one that uses `deferred`, which is what you should be using in this case.  https://jsfiddle.net/twler/aujqcmhv/1/

Hopefully it will clear up a bit about promise objects, as they can be confusing.

Comment: really strange, I got the same behavior after trying this approach.

Comment: here's the fiddle just for editing purposes. https://jsfiddle.net/adjavaherian/dzzas97p/

Comment: Please set it up so that it is reproducing your error

Comment: See my jsfiddle above

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting `done` right after `start` as you are not returning result of `workCollection(results)` in your then so its getting resolved with `undefined` right away. Try this

```
.then(function(){
    return workCollection(results)
})
```

Also, as suggested, go with `Promise.all` if the order doesn't matter otherwise your `Promise Waterfall` approach as also described [here](https://remysharp.com/2015/12/18/promise-waterfall) is fine.

Answer (score 1):

the mistake you are making is( other than not returning `workCollection` promise) `setTimeout` is not promisified, you can fix it like:

```
var q = require('Q');
var results = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function delayedCall(i, r, idx){
  return q.Promise(function(resolve, reject){  
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('item', i, 'result', r, 'index', idx);
      resolve(true); 
    }, 1000 * idx);
  });
}

function workCollection(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(promise, item, index) {
    return promise.then(function(result) {
      return delayedCall(item, result, index);
    });
  }, q(true));
}

q().then(function(){
  console.log('start');
}).then(function(){
  return workCollection(results)
}).then(function(){
  console.log('done');
}).catch(function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
```

[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dzzas97p/3/), I have used `Q.defer` instead of `Q.Promise` but rest of code is same

Comment: thanks @mido, I think you solved the problem, but there's a bug where the index appears to accumulate the set timeout.  so the last log takes five seconds from the second to last.